# Uniformly charged sphere inside a dielectric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

Consider a metal sphere of radius $b$ with uniform surface charge inside an insulating material with permittivity $\epsilon$. I want to calculate $E$ and $D$ in the dielectric region. I set up a a Gaussian spherical surface with radius $r>b$ around the sphere. I see two options here; (a) Compute $E$ using the total charge, then compute $D$, or (b) compute $D$ using the free charge contained in the gaussian surface, then compute $E$. Which is the correct choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choice (b) is exactly the right approach. You dont really know what the total charge is in order to do (a) until you do (b). The dielectric will put some more (or subtract some) charge from the spherical surface, and put an equal and opposite charge on the outside of the dielectric surface to maintain its dielectric constant.